# approximation to maximum and minimum function : soft-min and soft-max

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

The approximation to the function $max(x)$ can be written as a NOISY-OR as given below: $$ max_k(x) = 1-\prod_k(1-x) $$

Are there any way to approximate $min(x)$ ?

Comment: Could you please explain what "$x$" might be and in what sense your notation--which conventionally refers to a *product*--is a "noisy or"?

Comment: x is an array of real values (or x contains the output of a function). For example the approximation of max is explained in http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/168731/1008%20%281%29.pdf

Comment: Normally people only write about one of $\min$/$\max$ because the treatments are perfectly symmetrical.  For instance, if you view your $x$ as a "noisy" version of binary ($0$/$1$) data, then why not just find $x^{*} = \max(1-x_k)$ and use $1-x^{*}$?

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. My problem is max function cannot be differentiable. therefore I am looking for its soft versions. I think I can replace the min function by simply \prod(x_k) .

Comment: @user570593 Can you use the fact that $\min(x) = \max(-x)$? It sounds like you want to optimize a function involving a max function? Do you know about [Subderivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative), [Subgradient methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgradient_method), and [Convex optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization)?

Comment: Are you interested in the maximum of a function or in the $\ell_\infty$-norm of a vector? $\| \mathbf{x} \|_\infty = \max_k  |x_k|$.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply:

$$min_k(x) = 1-max_k(1-x) = \prod_k x$$

It doesn't really approximate the minimum or maximum though, as the returned value will always be more extreme and this will be exacerbated for high-dimensional vectors.

Instead you might want to try the Generalized Mean (a.k.a. Power Mean) with a suitably large exponent: as the exponent approaches $-\infty$ or $\infty$, the Generalized Mean increasingly approximates the minimum and maximum functions.